# Getting an Animation's Frame as a Texture using C#

Tags: godot

I have this code I want to use to generate Frames resources from a reference Frames resource, so that these new resources would have the same animations, only using different (same size and layout) sprite sheets.

```
public void UpdateTexture(Texture _texture){
            SpriteFrames _referenceFrames = Sprite.Frames;
            SpriteFrames _updatedFrames = new SpriteFrames();
            foreach (string _anim in _referenceFrames.GetAnimationNames()){
                GD.Print(_anim);
                if (_anim != "default"){
                    _updatedFrames.AddAnimation(_anim);
                    _updatedFrames.SetAnimationSpeed(_anim, _referenceFrames.GetAnimationSpeed(_anim));
                    _updatedFrames.SetAnimationLoop(_anim, _referenceFrames.GetAnimationLoop(_anim));

                    for (int i = 0; i < _referenceFrames.GetFrameCount(_anim); i++)
                    {
                        AtlasTexture _updatedTexture = _referenceFrames.GetFrame(_anim, i).Duplicate();
                        _updatedTexture.Atlas = _texture;
                        _updatedFrames.AddFrame(_anim, _updatedTexture);
                    }
                }
            }
            _updatedFrames.RemoveAnimation("default");

            _referenceFrames = _updatedFrames;
        }
```

Using this code, I get an error; apparently, calling `_referenceFrames.GetFrame(_anim, i).Duplicate();` returns an object of type Resource, not Texture. What can I do to get this Frame as a Texture so that the code properly executes?

Answer (score 0):

> Using this code, I get an error; apparently, calling _referenceFrames.GetFrame(_anim, i).Duplicate(); returns an object of type Resource, not Texture. What can I do to get this Frame as a Texture so that the code properly executes?

Cast it.

What happens is that `_referenceFrames.GetFrame(_anim, i)` is a `Texture`... But `Duplacate` is defined in `Resource` (which is the base class of `Texture`) and it returns `Resource`. *It is like old school .NET `Clone()` which returns `Object`.* But what it returns is actually of the same type of the object you calling it on.

So cast it. For example:

```
_referenceFrames.GetFrame(_anim, i).Duplicate() as Texture
```